# Merging data tables to form one master table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I have multiple sheets containing a table each which I want to merge to form a master table sheet. I also need this master sheet to be updated automatically incase we make any changes to the tables forming this master sheet.

I have been searching for 5 days but no success so far. I also got MS Office 2013 and tried with the Power Pivot etc. but they all seem useless. So now, I am ready for any inputs from the experts here who can help me with this issue. I don't want to manually copy and paste the data to create a master sheet because we update the data daily and the rows increase every minute. I mean, the data entry team here keeps feeding the data in.

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: i believe what you need is an actual database, not a sheet.

Comment: No update after a month, with no clarification from the OP. This should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to merge your tables. Is it the same data that you want to merge? or the columns are different?
I don't know which version or excel you have, but if you go to your Data ribbon and click "Consolidate", you will be able to combine multiple worksheets into a master table, maintaining the links to the original data, making it easy to update.
Hope this helps.